# Selenium Python cannot reinitialize DataTable

Tags: python, selenium

I have a problem with Python Selenium that cannot fix until now. Specifically, the website has a box search and a table of result, I'm using Webdriver from Selenium to fill the search content into the box, send key ENTER then get the data from the table, but it warns that the DataTable cannot initialize. So how can I fix this? My code is as below

```
string_date = datetime_.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '<some XPATH>')[0].clear()
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '<some XPATH>')[0].send_keys(string_date)
driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '<some XPATH>')[0].send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

table_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="table-one"]/tbody')[0].find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr") #
```

I have tried to put `time.sleep()` and `WebDriverWait` before find table element but  it does not work.

Comment: Pardon, but where is `DataTable` in this code?

Comment: the table has been visual already after reaching the webpage by ```driver.get(url)```.